# Who are these Discworld wizards from this picture?

Tags: character-identification, discworld

I haven't read many of the novels about wizards yet and would like to know who they are.

[image: The wizards in question]

[Image by [Paul Kidby]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Kidby)

Comment: I know that the mon-I mean ape is the librarian.

Comment: Don't call him a mon,....

Comment: The (current) top answers and their sources are wrong. [This is the correct answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/215059/13024).

Comment: @OrangeDog I've updated the source, given the overwhelming authority of Burgi's answer. Let's see how long it stays fixed

Answer (score 45):

The Discworld & Terry Pratchett Wiki has the full and, I believe, original image of the one in your question on the page [Unseen University](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Unseen_University). It is captioned thusly:

> Left to right: The Lecturer in Recent Runes, The Dean, The Librarian, The Archchancellor, The Senior Wrangler, The Bursar, Ponder Stibbons, The Chair of Indefinite Studies and Rincew.... oh he's, er, gone.

[The original image of the one in the question of the *Discworld* wizards.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxKWh.jpg)

Adding annotations, we have:

[image: The annotated image]

1. The Lecturer in Recent Runes
2. The Dean
3. The Librarian
4. The Archchancellor (Mustrum Ridcully)
5. The Senior Wrangler
6. The Bursar
7. Ponder Stibbons
8. The Chair of Indefinite Studies
9. ?

Rincewind is not in the image but is noted in the caption for it.

Comment: I used hex color #00c00c (pronounced Ook. Ook!) for the digits.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think the flying creature is a swearword called into existance when the Hogfather and Tooth Fairy were assassinated.

Comment: The implication in the Wiki description is that Rincewind was there as Wizard #9, but left for some reason. This is perfectly in character for him, either to have run away or to have suddenly got caught up in something.

Comment: The description of the image on the wiki page is wrong.  Refer to Burgi's answer for the original image.

Comment: @Corey not any more, it's not!

Answer (score 23):

Gentlemen, PLEASE! (And ladies, and mon...apes - decidedly apes). This is an institution of HIGHER LEARNING! Let us be careful to use the Full and Correct Names and Titles of our colleagues AT ALL TIMES! Ahem...

#1 is The Chair Of Indefinite Studies. Not sure about the name - CHAIR!!!! WHAT'S YOUR NAME?!?!?! Oh, for heaven's sake, can't understand a word he says, always walking round with a biscuit in his mouth like that. HOLD THAT THOUGHT, CHAIR!!!

#2 - the Dean of Pentacles, dear old Henry...errr...what's-his-name. (Brilliant man, to be sure, but...well, I'm not sure I'm completely convinced of his dedication to dear old UU. But still, where's the man to go..?)

#3 - the Librarian, dear old...what? Don't say..? Oh, yes, I'd quite forgotten. Just "Librarian". And the M-word..? Don't use that either? (Given all these restrictions on perfectly normal forms of speech I rather wonder if he's worth all the troub...) Now, now, Librarian, just put me down - GENTLY! - and we'll say no more about it. Heh...

#4 is, of course, myself, Mustrum Ridcully, DThau, DM, BS, DMn, DG, DD, DMPhil, DMS, DCM, DW & BElL, currently Archchancellor of Unseen University, for the forseeable future, and I've foreseen a good bit of the future, let me tell you!

#5 is The Lecturer In Recent Runes (as opposed, of course, to the Lecturer In Ancient Runes). Not sure about his name, precisely, although rumor has it that it is definitely *not* Arnold.

#6 is, undoubtedly, Dr. A. A. Dinwiddie (spelled with an "O"), D.M.(7th), D.Thau., B.Occ., M.Coll., B.F., titled The Bursar. Isn't that right, Bursar? Bursar?? BURSAR?!?!?!?!? Oh, bother. Well, give him another frog pill, someone, and we'll attend to him shortly...

#7 is of course young Stibbons, the Head of Inadvisably Applied Magic, Praelector, the Master of the Traditions, the Reader in Invisible Writings, *and* the Camerlengo (although why this should be is a question I intended to leave open for the foreseeable future). And also Head of any other odd job I find lying about that no one seems to know how to do, or why, or when. Well, **someone** must..!

#8 - the Senior Wrangler, which is rather odd because we don't actually use horses around UU. Eh? What? Mathematics?!? We *NEVER* use that around here!!!

And while we're on the subject - we should take a moment to acknowledge the contributions of our colleagues who are not actually present at the moment, such as they are. **And** they are:

- the Head of Post-Mortem Communications
- the Professor of Applied Anthropics
- the Professor of Astrology
- the Professor of Revolvings
- the Professor of Extreme Horticulture
- the Professor of Recondite Architecture and Origami Map Folding
- the Professor of Recondite Phenomena
- the Professor of Logic
- the Prehumous Professor of Morbid Bibliomancy (also the POST-humous Professor of Morbid Bibliomancy, which reminds me - do we have an opening on the faculty? Bursar? BURSAR!!!!! Oh, dear. Well, someone prop him up next to the hat stand and find some of those pills he's so fond of - nice flavor but they upset my stomach...)
- the Egregious Professor of Grammar and Usage
- the Lecturer in Applied Astrology
- the Lecturer in Creative Uncertainty
- the Lecturer in Vindictive Astronomy
- the Reader in Woolly Thinking
- the Reader in Esoteric Studies, a.k.a. the Reader in the Lavatory
- the Chair of Oblique Frogs
- the Professor of Criminology

And of course, Professor Rincewind, who is:

- the Chair of Experimental Serendipity
- the Chair for the Public Misunderstanding of Magic
- the Egregious Professor of Cruel and Unusual Geography
- the Fretwork Teacher
- the Health and Safety Officer
- the Lecturer in Approximate Accuracy
- the Professor of Slood Dynamics
- the Professor of Virtual Anthropology
- **and** the assistant Camerlengo

so if both I and Stibbons were to pop off you'd get Rincewind as Archchancellor, so let that be a warning to you!

And #9 is...amazing! I didn't know there were any more of those things left alive! Rare, that is - deucedly rare! ***SOMEONE FETCH MY CROSSBOW!!***

Comment: While amusing, this answer (and TheLethalCarrot's) is wrong.

Answer (score 21):

This image is from the book "The Pratchett Portfolio" (ISBN: 0-575-06348-3).

[image]

According to the accompanying text:

> Pictured opposite: Caught in uncharacteristically non-eating mode by the iconograph, the current incumbents of magic's highest offices are, left to right:
>
> The Lecturer in Recent Runes, the Dean, the Librarian, Mustrum Ridcully the Archchancellor, the Senior Wrangler, the Bursar, Ponder Stibbons (Reader in Invisible Writings) and the Chair of Indefinite Studies.

There isn't any reference in the book to the flying creature.